# Why is my HTML-5 video playback so much smoother on Safari and how can I get it to run smoothly on other browsers?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, data-visualization

I'm working with a collaborator on a scrolling video animation where the video should play as you scroll down the page. We've gone through a number of iterations of video compression to get the video to play smoothly, and in the process have noticed that while even the biggest files play really well on Safari (mobile and desktop), even the smallest files are pretty choppy on other browsers. Our goal was to have our video running as smoothly as this [Scrolling Controls for HTML5 Video codepen](https://codepen.io/ollieRogers/pen/lfeLc/) example.

Why is this so much smoother on safari? We're trying to get it that smooth on other browsers, but are wondering if the requestAnimationFrame (which enter-view.js relies on)  function is more optimized for safari and if we should be opting for some other animation strategy.

Here's our code:

```js
const container = d3.select('#scrolly-overlay');
const stepSel = container.selectAll('.step');
const progressCounter = d3.select('#progress');
let vid = document.getElementById('v0');
const containerHeightMultiplier = 300;;
const vidUrls = [{
    format: 'webm',
    name: '10FPS_CQ_35',
    file: 'TestVidLowRes_VP8_10FPS_CQ35',
    size: "6.5MB"
  },
  {
    format: 'webm',
    name: '10FPS_CQ_45',
    file: 'TestVidLowRes_VP8_10FPS_CQ45',
    size: "4.8MB"
  },
  {
    format: 'mp4',
    name: '10FPS_RF_27',
    file: 'TestVidLowRes_H264_10FPS_RF27',
    size: "4.7MB"
  },
  {
    format: 'mp4',
    name: '10FPS_RF_40',
    file: 'TestVidLowRes_H264_10FPS_RF40',
    size: "0.5MB"
  },
  {
    format: 'webm',
    name: '5FPS_RF_40',
    file: 'testVidLowRes_VP8_5FPS_CQ35',
    size: '3.4MB'
  }
]
d3.select('#vid-selection').selectAll('button').data(vidUrls).join('button')
  .text(d => d.name + '.' + d.format + '-' + d.size)
  .on('click', (event, d) => {
    d3.select('#vid-source')
      .attr('type', 'video/' + d.format)
      .attr('src', "https://s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/tao.mo.2021/" + d.file + '.' + d.format)
    d3.select('#selected-vid')
      .text(d.format + ': ' + d.name + ' (' + d.size + ')')
    vid.load()

    vid.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
      console.log(vid.fileSize)
      d3.select('#scrolly-overlay .scrolly article .step').style('min-height', Math.floor(vid.duration) * containerHeightMultiplier + "px")

    });
  })




function updateChart(index) {
  stepSel.classed('is-active', (d, i) => i === index);
}

function updateVid(progress) {
  progressCounter.text(progress);
}

function init() {
  Stickyfill.add(d3.select('.sticky').node());

  enterView({
    selector: stepSel.nodes(),
    offset: 0.5,
    enter: el => {
      const index = +d3.select(el).attr('data-index');
      updateChart(index);
    },
    progress: (el, progress) => {
      progressCounter.text(progress);
      vid.currentTime = progress * vid.duration
    },
    exit: el => {
      let index = +d3.select(el).attr('data-index');
      index = Math.max(0, index - 1);
      updateChart(index);
    }
  })
  /*
  enterView({
        selector: container.selectAll('.v0'),
        offset: 0.5,
    progress: (el, progress)=> {
      progressCounter.text(progress);
      vid.currentTime = progress*vid.duration
    }
    });
  */
}

init();
```

```css
.filler {
  height: 20rem;
  text-align: center;
}

#scrolly-overlay .scrolly {
  max-width: 60rem;
  margin: 3rem auto;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  padding: 1rem;
}

#scrolly-overlay .scrolly article {
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 30rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

#scrolly-overlay .scrolly article .step {
  /* min-height: 500vh; now set dynamically */
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#scrolly-overlay .scrolly article .step:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#scrolly-overlay .scrolly article .step.is-active p {
  background-color: #008080;
}

#scrolly-overlay .scrolly article .step p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: #5b5b5b;
  transition: background-color 250ms ease-in-out;
  color: #f4f4f4;
}

#scrolly-overlay .scrolly figure.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75vh;
  margin: 0;
  top: 3vh;
  left: 0;
}

#scrolly-overlay .scrolly figure.sticky video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1%;
  left: 0.5%;
  width: 99%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#scrolly-overlay .scrolly figure.sticky #progress {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section class='filler'>
  <p>
    Scroll
  </p>
  <div id='vid-selection'></div>
  <h2 style='margin-top:10px;font-weight:bold;' id='selected-vid'></h2>

</section>

<section id='scrolly-overlay'>

  <div class='scrolly'>
    <!--  sticky graphic   -->
    <figure class='sticky'>
      <video id="v0" playsinline tabindex="0" autobuffer="autobuffer" preload="preload">
   <!--     <source type="video/webm; codecs=&quot;vp8, vorbis&quot;" src="https://static.observableusercontent.com/files/3e8f13f77456ac7c630d81e395bec55a90b9ab508d4602e2e11e5b3890fa8681b13ec1cc846cfc2e27b44989ca60536d448ee7d63f945eeca91301ca2a0bdce3"></source> 

        <source type="video/mp4" src="https://static.observableusercontent.com/files/503c7cf52dcf3efaf653791a8919f2f4e186aba59d6e264fd22e46b589c7348b536fa23cc348a62a12e33b5dbcb5d258e4205150326297de0f7842105cab67a2"></source>
 
        <source type="video/webm; codecs=&quot;vp8, vorbis&quot;" src="https://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/video/basics/Chrome_ImF.webm"></source>
     <source type="video/webm" src="https://s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/tao.mo.2021/testVid2.webm"></source>
     <source type="video/webm" src="https://s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/tao.mo.2021/testVid.webm"></source>

     <source  type="video/webm" src="https://s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/tao.mo.2021/testVid3.webm"></source>
     -->
        <source id='vid-source'></source>
      </video>
      <div id='progress'>0</div>

    </figure>

    <!--  step text   -->
    <article>
      <div class='step' data-width='10%' data-index='0'>
        <p>Text to Trigger Scroll</p>
      </div>
    </article>

  </div>

</section>

<section class='filler'>
  <p>
    End
  </p>
</section>
```

And here it is on codepen (it uses elements from The Pudding’s enter-view.js examples, and that "Scrolling Controls" example): https://codepen.io/ossermans/pen/LYLbPJd

Comment: I am on Windows, Firefox 92.0, and the video is smooth.

Comment: And BTW, Mac is always better. `;)`